# Angular route config not working in 1.2.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code based on Angular js framework from google.
The code define some routing and associate views to the url path.
the code is like this

```
var profileModule = angular.module('profileModule', ['ngResource']);

profileModule.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
                controller: 'profileController',
                templateUrl: 'Partials/profileList.html'
            })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    $routeProvider.when('/profile/:profileId', {
        templateUrl: 'Partials/profileDetail.html',
        controller: 'profileDetailController'
    });

});

profileModule.controller('profileController', function($scope, profileFactory) {
    $scope.profiles = [];

    function init() {
        $scope.profiles = profileFactory.query();
    }

    init();
});

profileModule.factory('profileFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource("api/profiles/:Id", { Id: "@Id" }, { "update": { method: "PUT" } });
});
```

The code was using version 1.1.5 of Angular, and it was working fine.

But then I tried to use the newer version 1.2.3

and the code is not working on this version.

it is giving this error

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

I looked on example on how to use routeProvider in 1.2.3
and I found this example from the web site

```
profileModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
.....
```

I tried this , but still the same error

I am using Angular from the CDN network , and specifically from here

```
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/angular-route.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to depend on the `ngRoute` module as well:

```
var profileModule = angular.module('profileModule', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular v 1.2, they've separated the routing into a separate file, so you have to include it in your code and then inject it into your module.

You can find the latest version here (angular-route.js):
http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.3/